# improve efficiency of a Buffered Reader

Tags: java, android, json

Hi so im using a api to run a search for books. 
http://openlibrary.org/search.json?q=prolog

i then run a buffered search (below) to read each line in and select the lines that i want using a IF statement

"title_suggest": "Prolog",

```
 URL search = new URL("http://openlibrary.org/search.json?q="+searchingTerm);//search string
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(search.openStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) //read file
```

for instance: if inputLine contains title_suggest add inputLine to an arrayList.

however this is quite slow and i was wondering if there is a more effecient way to read in the data?

Comment: It isn't 'quite slow'. You can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader.readLine()`. The slow part is your code that processes each line. Or possibly the server is slow executiong the query or delivering the data.

Comment: my issue is it skips 200-400 android frames

Comment: Your issue is that you have a bug or a peformance problem in your code. Post it.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to post your code for that. Though, really doesn't the URL have to return in a threaded instance anyway? Why not just parse it there. Why are you parsing something in the UI thread and causing it to skip frames. Seems like you should just chain that in with the network lag.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot imagine that the parsing is a giant time suck compared to retrieving the data over the internet. But, whatever you're doing, you're way better off using a genuine JSON parser rather than rolling up your own parser, especially if you're relying on if statements to do so.

Also, make damned sure your query sent to the API is as restrictive as you can make it, after all the more exact data they can give you the better off it is for all parties involved.

Comment: its for a search engine that allows a user to search for books

Answer (score 1):

> this is quite slow

`BufferedReader` isn't 'quite slow'. It is extremely fast. You can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

The slow part is your code that processes each line. Or possibly the server is slow executiong the query or delivering the data.

You're barking up the wrong tree here.